# Criar um textarea com opções de edição de texto

Tags: html, formulário, textarea

Preciso colocar um `textarea` onde a pessoa consiga editar o texto. Ex: escolher o tamanho da fonte, aplicar negrito, alterar a cor do texto, adicionar fotos junto com o texto (um parágrafo, 1 foto, mais um parágrafo, 2 fotos). Alguém pode me ajudar a ter uma luz de como começar a fazer?

Comment: Existem diversos plugins pra isso, um deles é o [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/).

Comment: Existem várias alternativas para isso. Já existe muita coisa pronta para uso e grautuita, basta procurar por: "WYSIWYG textarea editor". Para começar sugiro este plugin baseado em bootstrap: https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg Outras opções podem ser encontradas aqui: https://www.sitepoint.com/10-best-html-wysiwyg-plugins/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A maneira mais facil de criar este tipo de text area é utilizando uma biblioteca, eu aconselharia utilizar o jquery

**JQUERY**

O jQuery é uma biblioteca de Javascript “leve”, fácil de utilizar no sentido “escrever menos, fazer mais”. Esta biblioteca foi desenvolvida por John Resig, um programador de Javascript. O site oficial do JQuery fica em www.jQuery.com

**Resolvendo Problema**

Dito isso, você precisará incluir a biblioteca:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script>
```

Depois Crie o  javascript responsavel por criar a o painel de edição:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() }); // convert all text areas to rich text editor on that page

        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
             new nicEditor().panelInstance('area1');
        }); // convert text area with id area1 to rich text editor.

        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
             new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('area2');
        }); // convert text area with id area2 to rich text editor with full panel.
</script>
```

Depois crie seu html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>How to Create textarea into a rich content/text editor using jQuery</title>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="nicEdit-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
        new nicEditor({maxHeight : 200}).panelInstance('area');
        new nicEditor({fullPanel : true,maxHeight : 200}).panelInstance('area1');
  });
  //]]>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<h4>How to Create textarea into a rich content/text editor using jQuery</h4>
<div id="sample">
  <h4>Simple textarea</h4>  
  <textarea name="area" id="area" style="width:70%;height:200px;">
       Some Initial Content was in this textarea
  </textarea>
  <h4>textarea with complete panel</h4>
  <textarea name="area1" id="area1" style="width:70%;height:200px;">
       Some Initial Content was in this textarea
  </textarea>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Isso funcionará e criará seu painel de edição

Comment: Acho interessante adicionar na sua resposta o link para a biblioteca que permite essas customizações, a [NiceEdit](http://nicedit.com)

Comment: Não coloquei o link, pois ele pode quebrar e ela pode achar outra solução semelhante.